# Shouldn't C++ Map be a random access data structure, rather than a bidirectional access data structure?

Tags: c++, dictionary, bidirectional, random-access

Why is map a bidirectional data structure. We can easily access any element if we know by using its key, just like a array which is a random access data structure? Then should not a map be a random access data structure, because we can access any of its data without having to visit any of its previous elements.

Comment: I don't know what you call a "bidirectional data structure", but a `std::map` is in the family of *associative containers* per the standard. It associates keys to values. You can random-access it all you want but only via the keys. It's *iteration* is bi-directional only.

Comment: @mudit rustagi If you want a map that has constant complexity for acessing elements, you might want to take a look at `std::unordered_map`, it is implemented with a hash table, rather than a tree like `std::map`

Comment: @muditrustagi It seems that you are confusing `std::map` with `std::unordered_map`. Only the latter is implemented as a "hash map".

Comment: `std::map` usually is implemented as red-black tree, so item is found using binary search (complexity `O(log n)`).

Comment: And `std::unordered_map`'s *iteration* is forward only, despite it's "random access" lookup

Comment: _Why is map a bidirectional data structure_ - citation please. What do you think a bidirectional data structure is, and why do you believe map is one? It is described as modelling _Container_, _AssociativeContainer_ and _ReversibleContainer_ [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Comment: @Useless presumably "a *Container* whose (`const_`)`iterator` is (const) *BidirectionalIterator*"

Comment: Sure, but the question is about key lookup rather than iteration, and thinking about what the terms mean and where they came from might help OP understand their own question better.

Answer (score 3):

No.

The concept [*RandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) extends [*BidirectionalIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator) by also requiring that you can *add a number* to the iterator.

This has **no relation** to the `key_type` of either [*AssociativeContainer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AssociativeContainer) or [*UnorderedAssociativeContainer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnorderedAssociativeContainer). What would it mean to add 5 to "mudit"?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is map a bidirectional data structure

Why do you think map *is* a "bidirectional data structure"?

> Shouldn't C++ Map be a random access data structure

Why do you think it is *not*?

Why do you assume that "bidirectional" and "random access" are mutually exclusive?

Seriously, whatever source gave you these terms is either wrong, or you misunderstood it. If you won't say where your incorrect assumptions came from, we can't help you with that.

> We can easily access any element if we know by using its key, just like a array which is a random access data structure?

Yes, [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) models  [*AssociativeContainer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AssociativeContainer) just as you expect.

> Then should not a map be a random access data structure

Are you trying to ask why map is not *called* a "random access data structure"? That's just because we call it an *AssociativeContainer*, but the meaning is similar.

Are you trying to ask why map is not random access in reality, even though it supports lookup by key? Then you have to tell us what you mean by "random access" *apart from* being able to lookup by key.

The lookup operation is logarithmic rather than constant complexity, if that's the distinction you want to draw, because map is a *sorted* associative container.

The fact that map's iterator is bidirectional doesn't affect how you find elements by key. It just means that once you found (the iterator pointing to) an element, you can walk forward or backwards over its neighbours in sorted order.